# what's wrong with my code the hide and not change the background?

Tags: jquery

```
$("ul.haschild").hide()    
$("#menu2 li span").click(function(){

        if ($("ul.haschild:hidden")) {
               $('ul.haschild').show('slow');
         $(this).("background",'url("images/image.jpg") no-repeat scroll right 10px #004DC1');
            }
            else if ($("ul.haschild:visible")) {
             $("ul.haschild").hide('slow');
         $(this).("background",'url("images/image2.jpg") no-repeat scroll right 10px #004DC1');
            }

       });
```

what's wrong with my code ,the  hide  function not work and not change the background?

html code:

```
<ul id="menu2">
<li class="parent"><a href="/taxonomy/term/6">one</a><span></span><ul class="haschild">
<li><a href="/taxonomy/term/14">two</a></li>
<li><a href="/taxonomy/term/13">three</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/taxonomy/term/7">four</a></li>
<li><a href="/taxonomy/term/8">five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i have posted the html code. thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things missing / incorrect:

- First of all why would you look for every li in your menu when the menu item with a child has the class 'parent':

  `$('#menu2 li.parent span').click( function()`
- You would want to look only for the child of the menu item that was clicked:

  `$(this).parent().find('ul.haschild')`
- And last but not least, you should set your CSS / inline style with `.css('attribute', 'value')`

  `$('#menu2 li.parent span').click( function()
  {
      if( $(this).parent().find('ul.hasChildren:hidden').length > 0 )
      {
          $(this).parent().find('ul.haschild').show(500);
          $(this).css('background', 'background: ....;");
      }
      else
      {
          $(this).parent().find('ul.haschild').hide(500);
          $(this).css('background', 'background: ......;')
      }
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Your `if`-clause is incorrect. Change the following:

```
if ($("ul.haschild:hidden")) {
```

to:

```
if ($("ul.haschild:hidden").length > 0) {
```

Also, your second `if` is irrelevant. If the element is not hidden, it must by definition be visible. So you can just leave that one out.

Comment: i am sorry, it can't work, i add a line before $("ul.haschild").hide() the click event.

Comment: Flater,do you know why the code can't work. i want to hide/show the child content. and if the child content is show, use image2  as  the span background image.and if the child content is hide, use image1  as  the span background image.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on holidays :) If you still need an answer: `$("ul.haschild:hidden")` is not a boolean, so odds are the if-statement is not evaluated correctly. What you want to know is "does the selector `$("ul.haschild:hidden")` return items or an empty list?". This can be best tested by checking the length of the returned list, hence `$("ul.haschild:hidden").length > 0`. If no items are returned, the length is 0, and the expression is evaluated as false (0 is not bigger than 0). If 1 or more items are returned, the end result is true (any other number is bigger than 0).